# Find an unsuppressed line in a large script

Tags: matlab

I am running a script which is fairly large. In the output screen I get `ans  = 10`.

The problem is that the code is very large and I cannot pin point where this output is coming from.

Are there any tips to find the origin of this output within the MATLAB environment since I prefer not to have a random output on the screen?

Comment: The editor will mark that line and tell you "Terminate statement with semicolon to suppress output (within a script)"

Comment: [`checkcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of a single script file, you can programmatically invoke [`mlint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html) to return all warnings in the form of a `struct`:

```
L = mlint('my_filename'); % No need for .m at the end
```

Inspecting the structure you could see the following:

[image: Variable editor]

This structure has a field named `'message'` which contains various issues, among which is what we're after - `'Terminate statement with semicolon to suppress output (in functions).'`. At this stage you can run

```
find( strcmp({L.message},... % output is not suppressed on purpose
     'Terminate statement with semicolon to suppress output (in functions).') )
```

Then inspect the line numbers that get printed.

Alternatively, if you want to skip the variable editor, or want to inspect a whole folder of `.m` files, you can run [`mlintrpt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlintrpt.html) (in the case of a folder) or `mlintrpt('plotWithoutOutliers')` (in the case of a single file) and get a report in the following form:

[image: mlintrpt output]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

As Luis said: look for the `mlint` error. In code this is shown as an orange shaded `=` and orange wiggle beneath it; on the scroll bar on the right it shows an orange line which you can hover over to see what the warning is and click on to go to the warning.

Additionally I included the red errors for completion. These will cause your code to be unable to run. Same here, red wiggle + red line on the right.

Last, the square on the top right, by the arrow, will either be green (no problems), orange (warnings, but the code will be able to run usually) or red (code won't be able to run).

Answer (score 0):

Used Dev-iL's answer to create a simple function that will tell you the lines of code that are not suppressed. This way you don't need to inspect the returned lines in the structure L. Example: `lines = UnsuppressedLines('isEven.m')`

```
function [lines] = UnsuppressedLines( matlabScript)

    l = mlint(matlabScript);
    unsuppressedInstances = find( strcmp({l.message},'Terminate statement with semicolon to suppress output (in functions).') )
    if isempty(unsuppressedInstances)
        fprintf('No unsuppressed lines in script')
        lines = [];
    else
        lines = {l.line};
        lines = lines(unsuppressedInstances);
    end
end
```